# FND_RECORD_CHANGED_ERROR on OAF page

Tags: oracle-adf, oaf

I read the stack-trace and found that the error comes from `oracle.jbo.EntityImpl.lock()`. I read that is caused by [RowInconsistentException](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14022/oracle/jbo/RowInconsistentException.html). So the problem is data difference between my database and OAF page.

I put a break-point in the beginning of the method. I saw three interesting child objects: `mData`, `mOrigData` and `mChanged`. I saw that in my case `mData` content is identical to the database and `mOrigData` differes. How should I interpret it?

Answer (score 0):

I found that `mData` means state before OAF operations, and `mOrigData` - state afterwards. `mChanged` contains ids of changed attributes. In my case I already had a non-null value in the database (non-`null` in `mData`) but on the page I was losing that value and tried to put `null` into the database (`null` in `mOrigData`). The framework decided that it was wrong.

I also had another case: `updated_at` attribute in the database was larger than in the `mData` object. It turned out that the database processed the row in the background after 2 seconds, but OAF read the row earlier. When I was trying to commit, OAF found that its state is older in the database and threw the same error.